# EF CORE 2.1 HasConversion on all properties of type datetime

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I previously used DateTimeKindEntityMaterializerSource ([Git](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/4711)) to convert all DateTime to UTC when reading entities because the default was unspecified.

With EF core 2.1 the DateTimeKindEntityMaterializerSource no longer works but we can actually do this

```
         builder
        .Entity<ESDataQuotation>()
        .Property(e => e.CreatedDate)
        .HasConversion(v => v, v => DateTime.SpecifyKind(v, DateTimeKind.Utc));
```

However, I have many properties of DateTime and I would like if there is a way to make the conversion for all property of type DateTime.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Excerpt from EF Core 2.1 [Value Conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions) documentation topic:

> There is currently no way to specify in one place that every property of a given type must use the same value converter. This feature will be considered for a future release.

Until then, you can use the typical loop at the end of the `OnModelCreating` override where all entity types and properties are discovered:

```
var dateTimeConverter = new ValueConverter<DateTime, DateTime>(
    v => v, v => DateTime.SpecifyKind(v, DateTimeKind.Utc));

foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
{
    foreach (var property in entityType.GetProperties())
    {
        if (property.ClrType == typeof(DateTime) || property.ClrType == typeof(DateTime?))
            property.SetValueConverter(dateTimeConverter);
    }
}
```

Comment: This will give a warning if you have set warningConfigurationBuilder.Throw(RelationalEventId.QueryClientEvaluationWarning) on DbContext optionsBuilder: "A SQL parameter or literal was generated for the type 'DateTime' using the ValueConverter 'ValueConverter<DateTime, DateTime>'. Review the generated SQL for correctness and consider evaluating the target expression in-memory instead."
But no worries the generated SQL query is correct so you should ignore this warning.

Comment: As of EFcore 6 this question is no longer favorable; The "future version" is here, and see my answer on how to register a ValueConverter globally for all types of a model property.

Comment: @Dynalon Is this comment for me or for readers? I know how to do that in EFC6, no need to see your answer. Moreover all this is now in EFC documentation.

Answer (score 27):

As of EF core `v6.0.0-preview6`, there is a more elegant solution to register a ValueConverter globally. In this example I use a custom ISO8601 converter that converts to/from ISO8601 in UTC, always appending the `Z` in the end:

```cs
public class DateTimeToIso8601StringConverter : ValueConverter<DateTime, string>
{
    public DateTimeToIso8601StringConverter() : base(Serialize, Deserialize, null)
    {
    }
            
    static Expression<Func<string, DateTime>> Deserialize = x => DateTime.Parse(x).ToUniversalTime();
    static Expression<Func<DateTime, string>> Serialize = x => x.ToString("o", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

and inside your `DbContext` class:

```cs
protected override void ConfigureConventions(ModelConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder)
{
    configurationBuilder.Properties<DateTime>().HaveConversion<DateTimeToIso8601StringConverter>();
}
```

This avoids having to specify the converter for every model property individually.

Comment: Quite elegant indeed. Thanks.

Comment: But why is there a String type involved, don't you want to just indicate that the DateTime.Kind is UTC? Where does the String end up?

Comment: @Rory I use SQLite, and it does not have a dedicated date/time datatype, but uses string to store dates. The above code gives you maximum flexibility on HOW a date gets serialized into SQLite (or other DB). Not saying you should convert all your types to strings.

Answer (score 11):

Just thought I could throw in my two cents

There's an issue for that opened here: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10784

Ivan's solution will work for simple types like `DateTime` etc. but it will crash when using user-defined types when calling `entityType.GetProperties()` this is described better in the issue in the link above. To make it work with user-defined types you will have to use `entityType.ClrType.GetProperties()`.

For universal workaround you can use this extension method:

```
public static class ModelBuilderExtensions
{
    public static ModelBuilder UseValueConverterForType<T>(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder, ValueConverter converter)
    {
        return modelBuilder.UseValueConverterForType(typeof(T), converter);
    }

    public static ModelBuilder UseValueConverterForType(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder, Type type, ValueConverter converter)
    {
        foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
        {
            var properties = entityType.ClrType.GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType == type);
            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                modelBuilder.Entity(entityType.Name).Property(property.Name)
                    .HasConversion(converter);
            }
        }

        return modelBuilder;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the only thing that worked when trying to do this with lists and dictionaries as well.

Comment: @agritton can you share here your solution for handling lists and dictionaries?

Comment: @mreyeros sure here is the code. I'm using it to convert my lists and dictionaries to json columns. Actually it doesn't fit in the comment so I'll just add an answer.

Comment: I think that's the correct answer. Thanks, @Konrad !

Answer (score 3):

This wouldn't fit in the comment section so I added an answer. Here is the code I'm using to convert lists and dictionaries.

```cs
foreach (var entity in builder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
{
    foreach (var property in entity.ClrType.GetProperties())
    {
        if (property.PropertyType == typeof(List<string>))
        {
            builder.Entity(entity.Name).Property(property.Name).HasConversion(new ValueConverter<List<string>, string>(v => v.ToJson(), v => v.FromJson<List<string>>())).HasColumnType("json");
        }
        else if (property.PropertyType == typeof(Dictionary<string, string>))
        {
            builder.Entity(entity.Name).Property(property.Name).HasConversion(new ValueConverter<Dictionary<string, string>, string>(v => v.ToJson(), v => v.FromJson<Dictionary<string, string>>())).HasColumnType("json");
        }
        else if (property.PropertyType == typeof(List<List<string>>))
        {
            builder.Entity(entity.Name).Property(property.Name).HasConversion(new ValueConverter<List<List<string>>, string>(v => v.ToJson(), v => v.FromJson<List<List<string>>>())).HasColumnType("json");
        }
        else if (property.PropertyType == typeof(bool))
        {
            builder.Entity(entity.Name).Property(property.Name).HasConversion(new BoolToZeroOneConverter<short>());
        }
    }
}
```