# EF Core - Global setting for handling a specific type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Is there a way to specify a default value converter for EF core when it hits a certain type instead of having to specify it manually per entity in the fluent API?

Example:  When the type Guid is hit, EF core knows to use the sequential Guid generator.  How can we do the same with a custom type?

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over the entity types in the model and their properties to apply the conversion where appropriate.  See the below SO answer for an example:

[EF CORE 2.1 HasConversion on all properties of type datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50727860/ef-core-2-1-hasconversion-on-all-properties-of-type-datetime)